# CKEditor save with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Problem.

```
    <script>
function Update_Tabelle_Line(ident) {
    var params = {
       id: ident
       desc: CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData();
       };
       $.ajax({
            url: "/includes/update_site.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: params,
            success: function(output) {
              location.reload();
            },
            error: function(/* Params entspr. Doku */) {
               // Hier ggf. die Parameter zu Diagnosezwecken auswerten
           }
        });

     }
 </script>
```

This script does not work like that.
If I the function calls by button it saves everything but the HTML code or the code of CKeditor is not saved why?

Sry for my bad english. Its Google Translate.

Comment: `id: ident` + `,`

Comment: `desc: CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData();` without `;`

Comment: ` function Update_Tabelle_Line(ident) {
    var params = {
       id: ident + ,
       desc: CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData()
       };
       $.ajax({
            url: "/includes/update_site.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: params,
            success: function(output) {
              location.reload();
            },
            error: function(/* Params entspr. Doku */) {
               // Hier ggf. die Parameter zu Diagnosezwecken auswerten
           }
        });

     }
`  
Not Work

Comment: NO: `var params = { id: ident, desc: CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData() };`

Comment: I need the params with it to be forwarded for the next site

Comment: I know. Replace your `params` with `var params = { id: ident, desc: CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData() };` and it should work